# How to run a number aliased unix command with '!' mark

Tags: unix, command

I know that '!' is used to run the history commands. The command !ps will run the last ps command from history, Likewise !2000 will run the command with history event 2000. If I had 2000 as a command or alias, then how can I run my original command or alias.

My Execution:

```
alias 2000 = rm a.txt

2000
file removed

history
1999 ls
2000 ps
2001 2000
2002 history

!l
ls
a.txt b.txt

!2000
ps
 PID TTY          TIME CMD
 2300 pts/5    00:00:00 bash
 8980 pts/5    00:00:00 ps
```

I need to run my alias 2000(rm command) with !2000 as I executed the ls command as !l.

Answer (score 0):

You try executing the below command for executing 2000 as history command.

```
!#2000
```

for reference: man history

`!# The entire command line typed so far.`

Comment: please check with the answer and let me know